# Using summernote with meteor (Discover Meteor)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mongodb, meteor

So, I've been working with Discover Meteor, and I'm having problems.

I'm trying to insert what content inputted in summernote into mongo but I'm having a few problems.

post_submit.html

```
<div class="form-group {{errorClass 'content'}}">
     <textarea class="form-control" name="content" id="summernote"></textarea>               
</div>
```

post_submit.js

```
var post = {
  url: checkURLPrefix( $(e.target).find('[name=url]').val() ),
  title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val(),
  content: $(e.target).find('[name=content]').val()
};
```

lib/posts.js  (will say Match Failed error when submitting)

```
meteor.methods({
  postInsert: function(postAttributes) {
    check(this.userId, String);
    check(postAttributes, {
      title: String,
      url: String,
      content: function(content){$('[name=content]').html($('#summernote').code());}  
    });
```

I've tried `content: String` to input the data into mongo. It would work but when I tried to load {{content}} in the post_page.html file, it would just show the unrendered HTML codes. {{{content}}} would show to content properly rendered but would mess up the functionality of the sorting system based on votes.

I'm really lost here and I wish I could find a solution soon.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT1: Here is my post_page.html and what I see when I insert content: String and load with {{content}}

```
<template name="postPage">
  {{> postItem}}

    <div class="col-md-12" style="background:blue;">

        {{content}}

    </div>    

  <ul class="comments">
    {{#each comments}}
      {{> commentItem}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>

  {{#if currentUser}}
    {{> commentSubmit}}
  {{else}}
    <p>Please log in to leave a comment.</p>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbLLX.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: you should use summernote in a `div`, not a `textarea`.

And in `post_submit.js` you have to leave it like this:

```
var post = {
    ...
    content: $(e.target).find('#summernote').code()
};
```

In your `post_page.html` use triple brackets, because its HTML.

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="background:blue;">
    {{{content}}}
</div>
```